# Server Fault Moderator Cards

Tags: discussion, design, community

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place..

If you're a Serverfault moderator, would you be interested in having your own Serverfault contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out during your local tech meetups or conferences.

Below is a mockup:

(click on image to see full res version)

[image: Server Fault Moderator Card]

Of course Twitter ID/phone# are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL etc.

Comment: While I don't disagree with the idea, I would like to point out that an awful lot of users who aren't moderators also spend a disproportionate amount of time working to ensure the quality of content here. Just sayin'

Comment: Ok, try it this way - Couldn't the design be improved so that they aren't such an eysore?

Comment: @John, I like the design, simple and elegant, and definitely inline with current trends in monochromatic design. And besides that, you're not a Mod, you don't get one anyway. =P

Comment: I could write a three pages answer emphasizing that most sysadmins  are modest and dry people, but instead I'll just post it as a tl;dr: AWESOME!!! ME WANT!!!

Answer (score 12):

Man I love you guys. Free t-shirts, LOPSA memberships and now business cards (not to mention a very handy 32Gb USB stick).

However, I must say, I personally wouldn't have a need for them (same as I had no real need for a LOPSA membership).

What I might suggest though is perhaps provide them on-request to anyone who is going to be speaking at a conference or doing lectures or something and the person is in good standing within the community.

That way Ben's concerns are also addressed, and the cards get to where they'll do the most work.

Comment: Yeah, us mods aren't the only ones doing high profile work. Good point.

Comment: Ditto and thanks! Saved me from typing the same thing on this bitty phone keyboard.

Answer (score 8):

Honestly, when I'm out about in the community, the ServerFault t-shirt I got does a good chunk of the outreach portion. Now that some of the SE merchandising is available, that may become less useful.

Honestly, there are scant few times a year when something like that'll be useful. My new employers are less reticent about sending me to conferences so the chances of getting out and about there are much more likely than they were a year ago. That said, that's a 3x/year thing at best, and for the rest there is a `.sig` line. 15 cards would be an ample year's supply.

Unless I ended up speaking somewhere, that's when I might go through a handful or more.

In the end, it's probably not worth the trouble to print 'em up on spec, though having the *option* when I know I'll be in a high-contact environment would be nice to have!

Comment: Agreed, if you were going to speak or some similar high profile duty, these would be very valuable; otherwise, more of a trinket.

Answer (score 1):

OK, moderators have officially been mailed the form to obtain the cards. Stay tuned!